# Anchor tags to jump halfway down a page in NetSuite (SuiteCommerce Advanced)

Tags: suitecommerce

Does NetSuite SuiteCommerce not support anchor tags? I want to include some links at the top of my page that let the viewer jump down to that category (on the same page).  I know I have my code set up properly, but all that happens is that it tries to open a new page with no content on it:

https://www.prospectfastener.com/product-interchange

Answer (score 0):

## Using Anchor Tags with NetSuite SuiteCommerce

Bundled together a few answers from other Backbone related questions.  This can be used in custom extensions or it can be placed in to SMT `CMS HTML` Content as an inline script.

*Tested with SC 2022.1*

```js
// This breaks the function out of the try/catch for use on page
var scrollToAnchorFn = null;
// SB env keeps doubling loading inline scripts for testing
// This tests/sets its own property on the window to test against for that
if (typeof window.anchorSet === 'undefined') {
  try {
    window.anchorSet = true;
    // Call scrollToAnchor with anchor ID whenever you want to jump between points on a page
    const scrollToAnchor = (anchorId) => {
      try {
        var aTag = $(anchorId);
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
          },
          'slow',
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };

    const initAnchorScroll = () => {
      // Test if jQuery is loaded yet, if not set timeout and repeat fn
      if (window.jQuery) {
        // Check if document is already loaded and ready, run code now if dom is ready
        if (document.readyState === 'complete')
          return scrollToAnchor(PageHash);
        // Before images or styling is finished loading, move to part of dom requested which is ready
        return $(document).ready(() => {
          scrollToAnchor(PageHash);
        });
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        initAnchorScroll();
      }, 50);
    };

    // Get our page hash
    //  const PageHash = window.location.hash;
    // Snippet demo hash
    const PageHash = '#testAnchor';

    // Initialize on page load if hash detected in url
    // Since hashes return the #, 
    // we want a length greater than 1 to ensure there is an id
    if (PageHash.length > 1) initAnchorScroll();
    scrollToAnchorFn = scrollToAnchor;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

```css
.fillerDiv {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1000vw;
  background-color: #fedd00;
}

#testAnchor {
  background-color: #4285f4;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="fillerDiv"></div>
  <div id="testAnchor">this is test content down the page with anchor ID.
    <a href="#" onclick="scrollToAnchorFn('#testAnchor2');">Go to Next Anchor</a></div>
  <div class="fillerDiv "></div>
  <div id="testAnchor2">Second anchor tag</div>
  <div class="fillerDiv "></div>
</div>
```

---

*Old Answer*

I'm going to assume not, but I'd be happy to be wrong.

> Note: Anchor Tags are not supported by Content Delivery.

[NetSuite Applications Suite -- Understanding Content Delivery](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N2689274.html)